# Check logs with Jest and execSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am running a script that uses the command line, to test using Jest I am using `execSync` on the test section I am running this:

index.test.ts

```
import { execSync } from 'child_process'

const runScriptToTest = () => {
  try {
    // This should console.log 
    execSync(`node ./lib/index.js`, {  stdio: 'inherit' })
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any error that occurred during script execution
    console.log(error)
  } 
}
```

Once `index.js` runs, it produces a `console.log` that outputs 'Working...' how can I capture this on a describe test?

It's easy enough to capture returned strings, but I am having serious problems capturing `console.logs`.

Comment: For those who thumb down and then walk away, it would be nice to know what's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem I had, it works with this:

```
const runScriptToTest = () => {
  try {
    return execSync(`node ./lib/index.js`, { encoding: 'utf-8' }).trim()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return ''
  }
}


test('Check logs', () => {
  const output = runScriptToTest()
  expect(output).toContain('Working...')
})
```